# Postgresql index design: combined indexes ordered

Tags: postgresql, indexing, postgresql-9.3

I know that if I have two queries like:

```
SELECT * FROM fruits WHERE type='apple'
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM fruits WHERE type='orange' AND state='rotten'
```

then an effective index would be:

```
CREATE INDEX type_state_index_on_fruits ON fruits(type, state) USING btree;
```

Since it would be able to use the index for both the first and the second query.

However what happens if there is sorting going into this:

```
SELECT * FROM fruits WHERE type='orange' AND state='rotten' ORDER BY picked_at ASC
```

Can I effectively create an ordered index of type and state but ordered by picket_at, so that the database would not have to do the sorting after fetching row in both cases:

```
SELECT * FROM fruits WHERE type='apple' ORDER BY picked_at ASC
SELECT * FROM fruits WHERE type='orange' AND state='rotten' ORDER BY picked_at ASC
```

Comment: [Check the execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-explain.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want one index for both queries, I'd recommend one on `(type, picked_at)`.

If you need to have `state` in the index, you'll probably need two indexes.